# The equivalent of "toggleVisibility" for "enabled/disabled"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the equivalent of `toggleVisibility` (when used for `visible`/`hidden`) for `enabled` and `disabled`?

As an extra, the equivalent for `selected` and `unselected`.

Comment: Are you after a name for a computer routine?  Not really on-topic, but call it anything you want.  How about _toggleEnabled_?

Comment: I'm quite confused what you are asking about. Could you provide some more information please?

Comment: @Adam You got me. I know this isn't the right place to ask this, but it surely is the place that better fit. I guess `toggleEnabled` is my plan B if nothing better comes up.

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq Adam got it right, it's a name for a function (computer routine, as Adam said).

Comment: I'm not really sure this is an ELL question.  If I understand right, you want to toggle something between "enabled" and "disabled" states?  I would just call that "enable".

Comment: @stangdon Yes, but that working won't be correct when the thing is "enabled" as doing "enable" on it again will actually "disable", thus the need for "toggleXYZ".

Comment: Programming languages aren't really bound by English as we know it (or, in some cases, any language or reality ever known by humans - cf. Malbolge), so I'm not sure it's a great fit for ELL. That said, speaking as a programmer myself, I'd go with a simple toggleEnabled, perhaps toggleEnabledStatus if you're feeling verbose. Describes the operation and references what property you're modifying; about the only thing missing is what object you're doing it to, and if it's a generic method then that doesn't matter.

Comment: @DamienH I think I'll go with your (and Adam's) suggestion after all. I can't think of anything better.

Comment: @stangdon: I think my answer from a linguistic perspective is a reasonable sign that it *is* an ELL question, although it's certainly true that it's much easier to answer for a programmer. However, this question would probably be downclosevoted on [Programmers.SE], so in the interests of giving it a place to live, I think it's fair to stick it here.

Comment: This question would be downclosevoted on any of the relevant SE communities because it's sorely lacking in relevant details. As @DamienH said, the choice of name should depend on what is being enabled/disabled, e.g. whether access for a user or group is enabled, whether periodic updates are enabled, etc. This would only belong on ELL if this were a question regarding the linguistics semantics of the word "enabled", and even then, I would rate it as a 50-50 tossup between ELL and english.SE.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Yes, you can answer it from a linguistic perspective, but that doesn't mean it's a great ELL question - otherwise, there wouldn't be English.SE, no?  The "Ask a question" page says "Is your question about learning the English language?  We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed." by which criteria I don't really think this fits.  But whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wanting to toggle some property or aspect of state represented by an nominalized adjective. For the property of being able to be seen, that's simple, as the noun is right there: "visibility". However, there is no such noun form for "enabled", and only dubiously one for "selection" ("selectedness", which is awkward, and "selection", which has the wrong implications — it's almost always used for a range of selected text).

Instead, use the past participle for each, resulting in `toggleEnabled` and `toggleSelected`.

Comment: As soon as you declare something 'as clear as can be', you're just asking for Fate to reach down and punish you for your hubris. :P

Answer (score 0):

Answering this borderline off-topic Q from a language-perspective...

The bare past-participle adjective **enabled** admits a yes/no answer.  So there's no need to wrap it in a toggle, as in *toggleEnabled*.

`something.Enabled = true/false`.

You cannot generate a method name from it because you haven't specified *that which is enabled or disabled*, as you did with **toggle*Visibility***.

**Enabled** would be property, not a method.

If you want to make a method (action) called Enabled, it would need two arguments, the object-behavior, and the boolean:

```
Enable( objectBehavior ob, bool value)
```

If you wanted to refer to a specific property:

```
myobject.EnableFlashingLights(bool value)
```